# Git log by only the filename to detect if the filename ever existed in the repo

Tags: git, git-log

I want to see a file with a certain name exists or ever existed in a git repo querying by only the file name (In a case where I do not know the full file path).

I can use `git log --follow -- <full filepath>` to see commit history of a file with full filepath even when it is removed/moved from the given file path. 
However I cannot do with by providing only the filename.
For example,

```
git log --follow -- xbmc/input/AppTranslator.cpp
```

shows me results but,

```
git log --follow -- AppTranslator.cpp
```

doesn't show me anything.

How to detect if a filename ever existed in a git repository and get its full filepath(s) and commit history?

Comment: You could add do `git log --follow -- *AppTranslator.cpp` but this will find any file that ends in `AppTranslator.cpp` Also the `--follow` should find any renames.

Comment: I had provided an answer, but this one is better because you are globbing. The only thing would be to enclose it in ''s so that bash doesn't expand it, just in case. `git log --follow -- '*AppTranslator.cpp'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers from the comments were correct.

```
git log --follow -- '*AppTranslator.cpp'
```